# How can I stop an image from losing its opaque property when I hover over some text above it?

Tags: html, css, image, text, hover

So I'm trying to make an image go opaque to show a black background behind it and make some text appear when I hover over it, however when I hover over the text the image stops being opaque.

Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Sorry if my question is a little vague. Here is an example of my code that might make it more obvious what I'm trying to do.
http://jsfiddle.net/0vvsbyjw/1/

here is my html

```
<article>
    <div id="image-wrap">
        <a href="recipe.html"><img src="https://theecosexuals.sites.ucsc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/94/2015/01/Planet_Earth.jpg" alt="Earth"></a>
        <a href="recipe.html"><h2>TEXT</h2></a>
    </div>
</article>
```

and here is my css

```
article {

position:relative;

}

article img {

display:block;
width:100%;

}

article #image-wrap {

background-color:#000;
z-index:-50
}

article img:hover{

opacity:0.6;
z-index:20;

}

article h2{

font-size:2em;
color:#FFF;
position: absolute;
top:40%;
left:0px;
right:2%;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
z-index:-20;


}

article:hover h2{

font-size:2em;
color:#FFF;
position: absolute;
top:40%;
left:0px;
right:2%;
text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    z-index:1;


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the effect appear when you hover over the article, so change:

```
article img:hover{
    opacity:0.6;
    z-index:20;
}
```

with:

```
article:hover img{
    opacity:0.6;
    z-index:20;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0vvsbyjw/3/)

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked. I've been trying to figure that out for so long. You're the best!